# What is necessary from a language implementation point of view to implement type providers like in F# 3.0?

Tags: database, f#, language-design, type-providers

F# 3.0 adds [type providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), which make it basically unnecessary to manually write or generate mappings between a DB (or another data provider) and the language/type system, because the language can query structural information from the database itself directly with type providers.

What is necessary from a language implementation point of view to add such a feature to a language?

Does it require a fully pluggable type system? Or is it more like some hidden code generator integrated into the compiler?

What's necessary to implement a new type provider for F#?

Comment: Re the last line; see the page you linked: "Where necessary, you can create your own custom type providers, or reference type providers that have been created by others."

Comment: This was tagged C#, and is distinctly not about C#. Removed the tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Technically, you can think of F# type providers as "plugins" for the compiler. Instead of generating mappings, the compiler asks the type provider "What types do you know?" or "Do you know this type?" (depending on the context).

The plugin (type provider) answers and specifies what the type looks like (abstractly, without actually generating it). The compiler then works with this information and later asks the type provider to provide code that should be used when compiling code that uses these "fake" types. It is also possible to actually generate code (some samples do this, because they just use tools that are already there).

So yes, you can implement your own type provider. I said a few things about it in the [GOTO Copenhagen talk](http://tomasp.net/blog/goto-loosely-structured-data.aspx) which has been [recorded](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GOTO/GOTO-2011-Copenhagen/Accessing-loosely-structured-data-from-F-and-C) and Don Syme said a few things in his earlier talks (I didn't see his BUILD talk yet).

Answer (score 3):

The API docs show that the 'type provider interface' is surprisingly small, see [ITypeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323952%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and [IProvidedNamespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323939%28v=VS.110%29.aspx), as well as the whole API [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340518%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) it is in.  Tomas' answer gives an overview, and the API docs show the specific interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

As [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) exists, it will probably be possible. But you're reffering to things that are in beta currently, so things might change.

As I understand the available documentation, the inferred types will be strongly typed, so I assume it's more  a compiler thing than a language thing ( besides maybe some syntax ).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the MSDN docs for ITypeProvider and IProvidedNamespace 
I can't see the documentation for the actual methods you would use to define the types, 
ProvidedTypeDefinition(x,y,z) and ProvidedPropertyDefinition(x,y,z)

perhaps it's this http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8670#195262

I can see from the examples that you can specify that a provided type derives from a known base class, but is it possible to specify that a provided type implements one or more existing interfaces? Seems like something you would want to be able to do, provided you can also provide the method body for the implementation.